# Биндинг к свойству элементов коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть код по типу такого:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public object SomeThing { get; }
}

public ObservableCollection<A> AList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<A>();
```

И есть ListBox элементы которого надо забиндить на элементы коллекции AList. Точнее только на их свойство Name. Вот как это сделать? Только чтобы не разносить это в две коллекции. Не хотелось бы.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: а xaml покажите как пробовали?

Comment: DisplayMemberPath="Name"

Comment: @Grundy да то то и оно что никак еще не пробовал. Я не знаю как разделить элементы списка на Name и Something.

Comment: @DarkByte: Как правильно написано выше, почитайте про `DisplayMemberName`, если вам нужна только строка. Если что-то большее, то установите `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: DisplayMemberPath вполне достаточно спасибо!

Comment: @vitidev: Может, опубликуете как ответ?

Comment: @VladD я думаю такие вопросы нужно удалять после ответа. Ну это же основа основ

Comment: @vitidev: Вы слишком строги, ТС-то не знал. Сюда зато будет приводить гугл потом :)

Comment: @vitidev А как сделать тоже самое, но у DataGrid? Т.е. забиндить какой то столбец на тот же самый Name. У столбцов вроде нет свойства DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: И еще как быть если я хочу сделать ListBox редактируемым? (добавил код в пост) Мне пишет "Нельзя одновременно задать значения DisplayMemberPath и ItemTemplate."

Comment: Хотя возможно это была не очень удачная реализация. Может кто лучше подскажет? Смотрится отвратно. Редактирование должно включаться при двойном клике только. Это как с TreeView.

Comment: @DarkByte у столбцов есть Binding={Binding Name}. Нельзя использовать DisplayMemberPath и ItemTemplate. А в ItemTemplate нужно делать ...={Binding Name}.